# how to create a grid of points within an irregular polygon with the maximum number of points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, grids-graticules

I usually use qgis and arcgis.
I need to create a grid of points within a polygon with the maximum number of points. I also need to set the grid parameters: x distance, y distance, offset from the border of the polygon.
I would like to develop grids as in the examples (the first example is a grid where the rows are equal two by two; the second example is a grid where the y axis is inclined)
I need this grid to fit inside rectangle or rhombus(image3).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did this through an iterative process for fitting a grid into a cut block maximize points, but they needed to tie into one of several benchmark which were a vertex on polygon's boundary while conforming to certain COGO type rule... so my set of options were only a few hundred whereas without some sort of constraint I think you might need a more clever approach then brute force. Any constraints on your grid? Orientation? The graphic you show doesn't look like a grid.